# Can't launch Jupyter Notebook at all

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I recently installed the Anaconda Navigator (Anaconda 2) on a Windows 8.1 machine.

If I launch Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda window, I am met with a 'Page cannot be displayed' error in my browser (Chrome).[image]

I have tried launching Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Prompt (no notable error message output). I have also tried opening the Notebook in a different browser (Firefox), and I have tried running the Prompt in Administrator mode. No luck.

I have Jupyter Notebook version 5.6.0 according to the Navigator, but if I type jupyter --version at the prompt it says 4.4.0 (wondering if this is a problem?)

I kind of expected to be able to launch a Notebook right off the bat after installing Anaconda. Is there some set-up I have missed?

(Edit) Tried a few more things, after reading the Jupyter Notebook docs. Tried replacing 'localhost' in the URL with 127.0.0.1, and tried opening the link Chrome with --disable-web-security. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Steps which i will advice:

1) Open your command prompt in the directory which contains your notebook or where you want to create new notebook.

2) Write `jupyter notebook` in cmd and press enter.

If jupyter notebook is properly installed then it will certainly open, else try reinstalling it.

Note: You can always update your jupyter notebook via conda or pip. At time if you update or install package/IDE via pip, Anaconda terms it as "broken link" and give issue.